# 7zip, xz, gzip, tar, etc -- what are the differences?

Tags: tar, compression, gzip, archive, p7zip

what factors should be considered when choosing among 7zip, xz, gzip, tar, etc. for compressing and archiving files?

Comment: This is opinion-based and is likely to be closed.  Edit it to be a objective and it might be a very interesting question.

Comment: I have seen gzip most of the time and compression level is good too.

Comment: If you want the best bang for your multi-cpu bucks, then you must consider pzstd. It is, however, not widespread. https://github.com/facebook/zstd/tree/dev/contrib/pzstd

Comment: I don't think title question is opinion based nor it should be closed as it's not been actually answered.

Answer (score 46):

I first want to clarify that, of the list you provided, `tar` is the only one that is **not** a compression algorithm. `tar` is short for **T**ape **Ar**chive, and is used to create archive files. In short, a single file that consists of one or more files.  It is used to bundle files together so that they can be compressed by a compressor that is only able to compress a single file.

In terms of availability, `zip` is widely available across UNIX (Linux/BSD/MacOS) and Windows systems. Therefore a `zip` file is highly portable. Tools to compress/decompress `xz` and `gzip` files are also available on Windows systems, but are more commonly seen and used on UNIX systems.

`xz` and `7zip` are known to have a better compression algorithm than `gzip`, but use more memory and time to compress/decompress. This topic is nicely discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108103/125535).

I would recommend using `gzip` when less memory is available, and compression/decompression speed is a concern. `7zip` and `xz` can be used when space is a concern and compression/decompression speed is not.

Some nice benchmarks on these algorithms can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220702171752/http://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO). **Note:** `LZMA` is the compression algorithm used by `7zip` and `xz`.

Answer (score 5):

Only answers the original question within the original context.  The question:

> What would you recommend me to use: 7zip, xz, gzip, tar, etc which is more or less available on the most linux distributives and what does compression the best?

---

Just use tar with gzip a la `tar -czvf <filename.tar.gz> /path/to/files`

Very often the difference in compression algorithms is either negligible (e.g. bzip2) or is dependent on what kind of data you are talking about.  For general-purpose compression, the best advice I think is just to stick with what is standard.

Also it just makes life easier to use the same formats as everyone else unless there is a clear and significant advantage.  So you'll want to get used to just using tar with gzip (as above) and also ZIP because you'll find a lot of those available as well.

Comment: @Jio because tar.gz is the defacto standard for UNIX. Since 1994 I have not found a single UNIX system, that this did not work on.

Comment: for some kind of files i found 7zip to make a really big difference. E.g. compressing a folder with javadoc the differece with a zip file is very big