# what the best approach in order to compress directory with Hundreds of sub directories

Tags: linux, tar, zip, cpio

Under `/usr/cti/APP_sys`, I have hundreds of directories and subdirectories and files, etc.

I wonder what the best approach in order to compress the `/usr/cti/APP_sys`  directory (get the best low capacity of `APP_sys`).

Meanwhile I use the following command

```
   tar –zcvf  APP_sys.gz  APP_sys
```

but my target is to find the best approach in order to get the best low capacity from APP_sys directory.

```
   tar Common Options:
   -C, --directory DIR
   -f, --file F
   -j, --bzip2
   -p, --preserve-permissions
   -v, --verbose
   -z, --gzip
```

Comment: What do you mean by "low capacity"?

Comment: I mean that the compressed file shuld be small

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which file compression software for linux offers the highest size reduction?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/which-file-compression-software-for-linux-offers-the-highest-size-reduction)

Answer (score 1):

You can decouple the "package all files together" part from "compress as much as possible" and play around with different compression options to see which has an acceptable trade off between time/memory/size:

```
tar cvf - ./APP_sys | gzip -9 > APP_sys.tar.gz
```

Or

```
tar cvf - ./APP_sys | bzip2 --best > APP_sys.tar.gz
```

Or

```
tar cvf - ./APP_sys | xz -9e > APP_sys.tar.xz
```

[Which file compression software for linux offers the highest size reduction?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/which-file-compression-software-for-linux-offers-the-highest-size-reduction)

Answer (score 0):

xz has the best rate of compression i have seen and is installed by default on most solutions.

```
tar -Jcvf APP_sys.tar.xz /usr/cti/APP_sys
```

Comment: maybe you need -j not -J ( see tar common options )

Comment: Nope, captiatal J - see tar manual, the captial J means you are using xz compression.

Comment: I dont have J capital

Comment: What verstion of tar are you using? run a: tar --version
If it is less than 1.27.1 then it might not be there.

Comment: see please the falgs that I use for tar in my question

Comment: If your tar version does not support the capital J flag you can still xz compress this way: tar –cvf APP_sys.tar APP_sys && xz APP_sys.tar

Answer (score 0):

The `tar` command will store one full path for each file.  Which can represent a great volume if the files are numerous and the paths are long.

You should try commands that manage a file index like `p7zip` .