# Cannot install lrzip

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation

I'm trying to install `lrzip` to compress big files as much as possible. Someone in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/which-file-compression-software-for-linux-offers-the-highest-size-reduction-for) pointed out that `lrzip` is the best tool to do this, so I want to give it a shot and see if I can achieve the highest level of compression possible (*BTW, I tried compressing files with `gzip`, `zip`, and `xz`, but the files are still too large for my purpose. E.g., the maximum compression I achieved with `gzip` was ~80% of the original size*).

[This response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/which-file-compression-software-for-linux-offers-the-highest-size-reduction-for#answer-119433) explains how to install the package using apt, but in my case I'm using Fedora 37 Workstation, so instead I tried to compile it from [the source](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip).

The first thing I do is type `git clone -v https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip.git; cd lrzip`. No issues with that. But when I run `./autogen.sh` I get the following error message:

> configure: error: Could not find lz4 library - please install liblz4-dev

I tried to install this library but couldn't find it. I guess it only exists for Debian?

As I mentioned before, my main goal is to compress big files (several gigabytes big) as much as I can, so if `lrzip` is not the best way to do this, I'm open to try other things.
Thanks!

Comment: It is called `lz4-devel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package in Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Alma Linux, Rocky Linux, is

```
lz4-devel
```

The command

```
yum install lz4-devel
```

will give you what you need.

Comment: As a general comment, the debian world tends to name development packages something-dev whilst the rpm world uses something-devel.

Comment: @icarus That's true and I normally explain that when I give answers regarding development packages in the Fedora family versus the Debian family.