# What file compression software/algorithm is best for mixed types of files?

Tags: files, backup, compression

I am looking to backup a large amount (~400GB) of different types of files (50% images and videos, 30% audio, 20% text). I hesitate to give an amount by which I'd like the size to be reduced, since I am not sure what would be realistic.

For the sake of simplicity, I'd like to be able to compress everything into one file. If it's advised to do it separately and then archive it all together, I could go with that. Since I wouldn't be doing this more than once a day, the amount of time it takes doesn't matter.

[This user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119433/471604) recommended `lrzip`, which in my test worked great with text, but did little with any other file types.

What compression software works best for this mix of files?

Comment: Forget about compression of video, images and (probably) audio. They are already compressed.

Comment: I would also suggest skipping compression of video, images (and probably audio, depending on encoding) etc, in other words: skip compression of already compressed files. Other files: executable programs, documents (with substantial amount of text) etc can be compressed with `xz` (with good results according to my experience).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- JPEGs can be losslessly recompressed to JPEG-XL, that will shave off ~20% of their size. Directly compressing JPEGs is generally futile - you may shave off at most 2% of something.
- PNGs are generally impossible to compress but you can use `optipng` to recompress them further or recompress them into lossless WebP or JPEG-XL. In my experience these two codecs can be twice as efficient but the process will be slow. Without recompression PNGs are basically impossible to compress further as they are already compressed.
- For video: most video codecs are essentially incompressible, specially anything that is newer than MPEG-2, i.e. VP8, H.264, VP9, H.265, AV1, etc.
- Text: that depends on what you want to achieve and codecs you want to use. There is a ton of them, if you're interested only in the most popular ones, `7z` and `ZSTD` will be your obvious choices.

https://encode.su/forums/2-Data-Compression is a good place to discuss such questions.

> What compression software works best for this mix of files?

None or anything *you* choose.